# Problems compiling Traffic library

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-18

I attempted to install the Traffic library for the book "A Touch of Class" but was not able to compile the examples. EiffelStudio complained about a base2.ecf file.
Error code: VD00

General configuration parsing error.
What to do: fix the configuration file.

Could not open file: \base2.ecf
$EIFFELBASE2\base2.ecf

base2.ecf is found in where Windows installed Eiffel: C:\Program Files\Eiffel Software\EiffelStudio 18.11 GPL\unstable\library\base2.ecf The offending line of code seems to be this in the Traffic configuration files:

I have attempted to change this configuration file pointing directly to where the file is, using the actual path, to no avail.

Comment: What happens exactly when you change the configuration file directly?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the variable `EIFFELBASE2` might help:

```
set "EIFFELBASE2=C:\Program Files\Eiffel Software\EiffelStudio 18.11 GPL\unstable\library"
```

Then, EiffelStudio should be started from the environment where the variable is set.

(However, I wonder if this is the library to be used with the examples, or if there is another one that comes together with the examples.)